# How can I run multiple instances of the same window service(java) in single machine

Tags: java, windows-services

I have a Java class (Java Application) and am running it as Windows service using the Java Service Wrapper.

Service s1 is already running as window service in my system. Can i install the same service and make it to run as duplicate. If yes, please suggest me a way to run a duplicate service.

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano - In some cases, there are advantages in running separate instances.  Lets assume the OP has one of those instances ... and answer the question *as it was asked*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the way you created your original service. You can give different services running same application(in this case your java application) same names also. But its advisable to give different names eg : XXXservice1 , XXXservice2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just give each service unique name, e.g. mysevece1, myservice2 etc. BTW it is even not required. It is for your convenience only.

Comment: @MukulGoel - each service instance would run in a separate JVM.  That means that the application doesn't need to be thread-safe ... unless it is internally multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the port number for the application and your application can be made running on the same machine.